# Do 自 and 起 work together here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This text is talking about the lights in 广州湛涌村。

由于如秋后，广州的日照时间缩短，自花苗上盆起，花农们就会利用电灯补光来延迟花期。

This bit confused me (I'm easily confused). Is it right that 自 ... 起 work together as 'from when' or 'starting from when' here?

自...起 since

**自**花苗上盆**起**
starting from when the seedlings are put in their pots

If this is right, you can clearly see the power of Chinese to express ideas in a very concise manner!

Comment: Your understanding is correct: "自花苗上盆起
starting from when the seedlings are put in their pots".

Comment: 延迟花期(delay the flowers selling period) is wrong. It should be "延长(prolong)花期"

Comment: "如" in "由于如秋后" is a typo. It should be ""由于秋后"

Comment: @ tsh "由于如秋后，广州的日照时间缩短" means the daylight time is shortened, The lighting is there  to make up for the lost daylight, It is hard to do business when it is dark. So "prolong the selling time" make sense but "delay the selling time" doesn't

Comment: the way to delay the start of flowing selling period until spring festival is not to sell them before it is time. using electric lighting is for  prolonging the selling time every day

Comment: And... "如" in "由于如秋后" is a typo. But it should be ""由于入秋后"

Comment: "入" in "由于入秋后" can be omitted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101548/discussion-between-tsh-and-tang-ho).

Comment: I think 延迟花期 here means: prolong florescence.

Comment: my typo, was correct 入 in my book

Comment: @TangHo 入 can't be omitted in 由于入秋后 because it will change the meaning. 由于入秋后 means *after entering the fall*, while 由于秋后 means either *at the end of fall* or *after the fall*.

Comment: I think 秋后 means "after fall arrived". not "after fall end e.g". 秋後斬 (Execution after fall arrived)，秋後算帳 , 秋後扇. after fall end is called 冬至 (winter comes)

Answer (score 4):

> 自...起 since

It is correct, "**自**???**起**" means "**Since** ???"

- 自 = from
- 起 = begin

> "(自) ??? (起)" = "(begin from) ???" = "**(Since)**???"
>
> e.g."**自**七月**起**禁止捕魚" (Ban on fishing **since** July)

Other common structures with 自:

> "**自**(from) ??? **以來**(thereafter)" = "**since** ???"
>
> e.g. **自**美國立國**以來** (**Since** the founding of the United States *thereafter*)
>
> "**自** (from) ??? **以後**/**之後** (after)" = "**since** ???"
>
> e.g. **自**美國立國**以後** (**Since** *after* the founding of the United States)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your understanding is right.

「自...起」 can be used for a point in time as well as in location.

For example, 「自第二层起，所有楼层都是住宅」 meaning that “from the second floor, all floors are residential”.